# My iphone's apps are copied onto someone else's phone each time they sync

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

My husband and I share a computer and iTunes. We have separate Apple IDs. When my husband syncs his phone, he gets a whole new page of all the apps from my phone. I can see as it's syncing, that it's "copying" apps that are only on my phone. How do I stop this from happening? He has to go through and delete all these extra apps each time.

Answer (score 1):

By default apps are copied to iTunes from the phone when syncing. By default apps are copied from iTunes to the phone when syncing. This can be annoying - personally it's my kids who put a thousand irritating games on their phone, but I can see that a husband would be just as bad.

Connect your phones to iTunes. Find them in the left-side menu, or drop-down.

Under the Apps menu you can turn off syncing.

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes, choose the iPhone,

[image: iTunes]

then Apps

[image: Apps]

and look below the window of apps.

[image: Automatically]

Is "Automatically install new apps" checked?